# Simple RoR app not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've successfully installed Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.14 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I know this because visiting localhost:3000 shows me the a page that says "Welcome aboard...You're riding Ruby on Rails!"

I'm following "Beginning Ruby on Rails" by Steven Holzner that was written in 2007 to create my first RoR application.  I've done the following:

1. `myshellprompt:~/rubydev$  rails hello`
2. `myshellprompt:~/rubydev$  cd hello; ruby script/generate controller App`
3. In app_controller.rb I added this to the class body

   ```
   def greeting
   end
   ```
4. I created this greeting.rhtml in rubydev/hello/app/views/app

   ```
   <html>
     <head>
       <title>Ruby on Rails</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <h1>Yes it's working</h1>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
5. `myshellprompt:~/rubydev/hello$  ruby script/server`

When I go to localhost:3000/app/greeting, I get an error that says "We're sorry, but something went wrong" instead of "Yes it's working!"

I noticed when I executed some of the commands I got a lot of "deprecated" messages.  What went wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: First of all, dump Rails 2. It is outdated. Second of all, dump Ruby 1.8. It is outdated. Third of all, have you checked your Rails router in router.rb ?

Comment: I completely agree with Niels and Leo that you shouldn't use ancient versions of Ruby and Rails. As for the error you are getting: check your log files to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: There's no reason for you to start off with an old version like this unless you're forced to work with a legacy rails app.

Comment: thanks everyone.  I wish I hadn't spent hours with RailsReady.  Strangely enough by default the latest version of ubuntu suggests installing rails 2.3.14 with sudo.  Anyways, time to google how to uninstall all this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Like the suggestion in the comment. Ditch the old versions of Ruby and Rails as they are outdated and you'll pretty much have to re-learn new things on the newer versions.

As for tutorials take a look at this excellent tutorial by Michael Hartl called [Rails from Zero to Deploy](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

It'll guide you through everything from building an app to deploying it and using git as well as TDD (Test Driven Development) .

As for your actual question, can you post your `routes.rb` file to help you better?

Also, if you can provide your server logs to show us the backtrace.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with routes.rb? There is nothing in his question that suggests that. He'd better look at his log files to find out what's wrong.

Comment: I forgot to ask for the logs. I figured the routes would show something wrong as the rest of the code that he has looks fine...